# How to avoid __pycache__ when using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I see `__pycache__` is alawys generated in the following example. Is there a different way use flask to avoid `__pycache__` from being generated?

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a *Flask* thing, but rather a *Python* one. The *__pycache__* *dir* is used to store the bytecode ("compiled" versions) of your source (*.py*) files (mostly, for performance reasons). *Python 3* does that by default. To suppress the behavior, pass the ***-B*** argument to the interpreter, as pointed out by: [[Python.Docs]: Command line and environment - -B](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id1):

> If given, Python won’t try to write `.pyc` files on the import of source modules. See also [PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE).

**Or** (if you run *flask.exe* directly), set the *PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE* *env var*, to something different than empty (`set PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=some_dummy_text`), before starting the interpreter.

Comment: How to use `-B` when I call `FLASK_APP=main.py flask run`?

Comment: In that case, use the 2nd option with the env var. Or you could try starting *Flask* using the other option from the docs (`python -B -m flask`).